# Windows Virtual PC and "Safety"

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

This is somewhat of a weird question, but let me explain.

I used to run Virtual PC 2007 to try out various operating systems, etc.  I really liked two things - one, the ability to roll back any changes that I made tinkering with the operating system.  And, two, I liked the fact that the OS was "sandboxed" so that if I really did something dumb, I would be protected from the problems affecting my main OS.

So, while I know Windows Virtual PC is a bit different, does it still offer this sort of protection (the second item above)?  If I run something in Windows XP mode, will my host OS be protected against any problems that may happen?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that XP mode doesn't let you run other operating systems. If you want to do this, try VirtualBox or VMWare Player.

Comment: @JoeInternet: You're wrong. XP Mode is Virtual PC + an activated XP image. You can also load other OSs (albeit the officially supported list is quite short).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since the software runs "inside" the Windows XP OS, and not in the host. Yes it pops out the main window, but it is just a window. Anything that happens inside the application does not cross over into the host environment.